# How to use IF + VLOOKUP?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, datatable, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to see if it's possible to get a function between IF + VLOOKUP. I would like to have a table where I can select a specific cell and based on that command a specific set of information is shown. I have tried with SORT + FILTER but since I have more of less 23 different columns to choose from, the information wasn't displaying the way I wanted to.

What somehow I've managed to do is just a SORT based on the total results but I would love if I could create one that filters it based on the cell or condition I want.

Here's a link on a test I tried to do so I could better explain myself https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i7f80FsWIMQtH1X6r7oEidymbJdGGJv2U5xQUZA7vC4/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for any suggestion that can help me or something near what I want.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Sure! I just added an example tab on the file; bascally that's what I want to achieve but making with 2 conditins for example, if add more countries make sure it only filters the country and the condition I select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(SORTN({Data!A2:A13, Data!AC2:AC13, Data!C2:C13}, 23,, 2, 1), 
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col3 = '"&D4&"'")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would this work even when the data I need to filter is divided on both columns and rows?

Comment: @May yes. ofc not in this form. it would need to be edited a bit to fit your exact scenario